# Values in a column that are in a %

Tags: sas, percentile

In Access I'd take the column I'm looking to get the data from select it.  Go to its properties, go to Top Values, and I'd put in the percentage I wanted of the current list.  For instance a Cost list.  1000 members, I only want to know the top 2% of cost of my members.  I place 2% in and the list shows the top 2% of cost of my members.

How can I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 5):

I'd just use `proc rank`.

`groups=100` creates 100 ranked groups based on the variable `var1` specified in the `var` statement. The `ranks` statement puts the groups into a new variable `percentile`.

```
proc rank data=have out=have_ranked groups=100;
  ranks percentile;
  var var1;
run;

data want;
  set have_ranked;
  where percentile ge 98;
run;
```

Comment: The extra data step is unnecessary - you can use a where clause on the out= dataset specified in the proc rank statement. For people unfamiliar with the proc, it's also worth mentioning that the first group is 0 rather than 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use proc univariate to get cutoff point for top 2%, then select obs you need. Something like:

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
    var weight;
    output out=cutoff pctlpts=98 pctlpre=weight;
 run;

data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   if _n_=1 then set cutoff;
   if weight>=weight98 then output;
run;
```